# Shared profile link in feed has insufficient data in JSON graph API

Tags: php, arrays, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was wondering if there is a way to show the actual profile that has been shared on the page feed. Right now the fields that are returned don't give much information.

I'm grabbing the feed as a json object, convert it to a php variable with json_decode and iterate over the returned array.

Everything works just fine except when someone links to a profile of a page in their feed.

```
$fields = "id,message,picture,full_picture,link,name,description,type,icon,created_time,from,object_id,source";

https://graph.facebook.com/{$fb_page_id}/feed?access_token={$access_token}&fields={$fields}
```

Regular data item:

```
[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 12312452343463463_31253215252
        [message] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
        [picture] => https://www.picture.com/ADSASD1223
        [full_picture] => https://www.picture.com/ADSASD1223_full
        [link] => http://www.link.com/
        [name] => Linkage
        [description] => Linkage is a link provider
        [type] => link
        [icon] => https://www.facebook.com/images/icons/post.gif
        [created_time] => 2016-02-23T16:07:05+0000
        [from] => Array
            (
                [name] => Test
                [id] => 1233434564567
            )

    )
```

Profile data item:

```
[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 31248734871234_312498341278341278
        [message] => Look!  It's John the Deer! Make sure to follow him!
        [type] => status
        [created_time] => 2016-02-21T19:16:24+0000
        [from] => Array
            (
                [name] => Test
                [id] => 1343143414314314
            )

    )
```

As you can see there is no link or no image for the actual linked profile.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. What do you mean by “the actual profile that has been shared”? You mean a post that includes 'https://www.facebook.com/username` inside the message text?

Comment: Or do you actually mean a profile that was _tagged_ in the post? In that case, look at the properties of the [`post`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/post) object – `message_tags`, and maybe `with_tags` as well.

Comment: I'm sorry that I wasn't clear. It is actually a shared profile with a message from the person who shared it. It's the same as someone shares a page or video except I can't get the actual shared profile data.

I've tried the fields you mentioned but to no avail, they didn't return anything.

Not sure if this helps but the status type is a shared story `"status_type": "shared_story",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [CBroe's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642743/shared-profile-link-in-feed-has-insufficient-data-in-json-graph-api/35669502#comment58980127_35642743) I got the ID from the particular post and tried all the fields for the `post` object.

The field `story_tags` ended up being the one.

It returns the following:

`"story_tags": [
    {
      "id": "0909030339039",
      "name": "Name of the person or page that shared the profile",
      "type": "page",
      "offset": 0,
      "length": 23
    },
    {
      "id": "91238193129",
      "name": "Shared Profile Name",
      "type": "user",
      "offset": 33,
      "length": 7
    }`

I'm not sure what the offset and length refer to but with the id value I can finally see and have access to the shared profile.

Comment: _“I'm not sure what the offset and length refer to”_ – that’s the position where the profile name occurs in the `message` of the post, and its length. They can be used if you want to f.e. link that part of the message back to the actual profile or something like that.

Comment: Ah I see, well thanks a ton CBroe for your assistance!